# Joomla Plugin Options

Tags: joomla1.5

I need to write a simple extension for Joomla. All I need to do is look for a URL query parameter, and perform a redirect if the parameter is there.

I thought a "System" plugin seemed most suitable (Didn't seem to fit any other category - search, authentication, content, etc..)

I wrapped my working code into a system plugin following Joomla Docs (http://docs.joomla.org/Reference:System_Events_for_Plugin_System#Overview), but the code has no effect.

Have I chosen the wrong type of plugin category?

**Update:**

Here is my code. I started with everything in onAfterInitialise - when that didn't work, I tried overriding all the methods:

```
<?php

 // no direct access
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );

jimport( 'joomla.plugin.plugin' );

class plgSystemMyFirstPlugin extends JPlugin
{
        /**
         * Constructor.
         *
         * @access      protected
         * @param       object  $subject The object to observe
         * @param       array   $config  An array that holds the plugin configuration
         * @since       1.0
         */
         public function __construct( &$subject, $config )
         {
            parent::__construct( $subject, $config );
          }



        function onAfterInitialise()
        {
          //I have my actual code here - then I added the print statements.
          print "It's working in onAfterInitialise";
        }

         function onAfterRoute()
        {
          print "It's working in onAfterRoute";
        }

        function onAfterDispatch()
        {
          print "It's working in onAfterDispatch";

        }


}
?>
```

Comment: What event triggers your plugin? Can you post some code? This should be a system plugin as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Brent Friar - I updated with my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your XML install file is correct, change the class name of your plugin to plgSystemMyFirst. The correct naming convention is plg<PluginGroup><PluginName>. I tried your code with the correct name and it worked just fine.